# DataError in datagridview when you see the row

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview

I have strange problem. I have `datagridview` fill from `XML` file and a `button` that add a new row at the end to that `datagridview`.

I have scrollbar so I can't see all the rows at once. When I add new row and if I **don't** see the new created row everything is OK.

The row is created and I can edit cell and everything is fine. But if I scroll down to the end and then press the `button` there is `DataError` in

```
 datagridview1.Rows[datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].
```

This column is special. It's `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and when it doesn't have value the 
I have - `DisplayStyle = Nothing`. But when I have values from the xml I make the `style` - `ComboBox`. **I have no problem with that.**

Here is the code that add the row:

```
private void AddNewBlock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  datagridview1.Rows.Add(val[0], 0, val[1], new DataGridViewComboBoxCell(), 4, 0);
  datagridview1.Rows[datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
  (datagridview1.Rows[datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;

  AddNewDataGridvRow(datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1, 3, true);
}
```

The method `AddNewDataGridvRow' contains:

```
private void AddNewDataGridvRow(int row, int col, bool isNewBBlock = false)
    {
       AddNewNumber newNum = new AddNewNumber();   // this shows form with one textbox 
       // in it you type the value. Nothing special.

       DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

       if (newNum.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)datagridview1.Rows[row].Cells[col];

            byte num= newNum.Num;

            cb.ValueMember = num.ToString();
            cb.Items.Add(num.ToString());

            datagridview1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = ver.ToString();
        }
```

Is there something that I do wrong? 
When I debug it I get the error after I press f10 in this line 
`if (newNum.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`

The form code:

```
public partial class AddNewNumber : Form
{
    public byte Num= 0;
    public AddNewNumber ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Num= Convert.ToByte(tbNum.Text);
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code of your form `AddNewNumber `? It seems the form does not work well. And also, have you any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you open the dialog :

```
        newNum.ShowDialog()

        if (newNum.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        }
```

`DialogResult.OK` cannot be compared to a `.showDialog()` I guess.

You must compare the `DialogResult` property of your form, with the value `DialogResult.OK`, not the `.showDialog()`.

Comment: I just need a number that is not bigger then 255.

Comment: What happend when you got through your form, in debug mode? Using f11 not f10.

Comment: The DataError happens when the new form loads. I am sure that the error is not related with that form. I think it's because of the ShowDialog().

Comment: Edit my answer. Try this. ShowDialog() and DialogResult.OK are not the same data.

Comment: I done it with F11 but before that create empty `AddNewNumber_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function so I can place a breakpoint somewhere. After the method `AddNewNumber_Load` it goes to the `DataError` method of the `datagridview1`.

Comment: I manage to fix it thanks for the help. The error comes from the line `datagridview1.Rows.Add(val[0], 0, val[1], new DataGridViewComboBoxCell(), 4, 0);`. I change it to `datagridview1.Rows.Add(val[0], 0, val[1], null, 4, 0);` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it thanks for the help. The error comes from the line

```
datagridview1.Rows.Add(val[0], 0, val[1], new DataGridViewComboBoxCell(), 4, 0);
```

I change it to

```
datagridview1.Rows.Add(val[0], 0, val[1], null, 4, 0);
```

and it worked.